# Classic ASP, Cookies, and VB.NET COM+ objects

Tags: vb.net, com, cookies, asp-classic, vb6-migration

This is tangled.

I've been handed a web site written in classic ASP, with a lot of behind the scenes stuff done in VB6 COM+ objects called from the ASP pages via Server.ObjectCreate() instantiations. For this incarnation, the VB6 routines have been converted to VB.NET simply by running the Visual Studio 2003 converter tool on them, and then upgrading that solution file to VS 2008.  So there's a thousand and one possible sources for error.

One of the VB6 Modules that is giving me trouble clears a bunch of Response cookies by lines of the following form:

```
ASPResponse.Cookies("SysUserCode") = ""
```

Where ASPResponse is defined as :

```
Private ASPResponse As ASPTypeLibrary.Response
```

And was set up on Object Activation by:

```
Set ASPResponse = objContext("Response")
```

In the VB.NET conversion of this module, those lines became

```
ASPResponse = ContextUtil.GetNamedProperty("Response")
```

and

```
ASPResponse.Cookies("SysUserCode")() = ""
```

(note the extra pair of parentheses. Not being much of a VB person, I'm not real sure what that syntax means.)

Okay, here's the question: When this code executes on MY machine, that line is giving a VB error 13, with the Error.Description being "Specified cast is not valid."  Huh?  What cast?

Incidentally, this module runs fine on a co-workers machine, and he cannot see any difference in the configuration of my machine and the relevant components from his.

I'm totally at a loss here.  Googling it has given me a bunch of stuff on VB.NET cookies, or COM components with VB.NET, but nothing related to classic ASP cookies.

Comment: Further investigation:  It appears that the "invalid cast" is actually occurring when the Cookies member of ASPResponse is accessed. Any code whatsoever that accesses ASPResponse.Cookies and anything beyond that throws the Specified Cast not valid exception. It makes me wonder if there's something wrong in the configuration so that what is being passed in from the ASP page, even though it as accessed by the named property "Response", is not actually an ASPTypeLibrary.Response object.  Just speculating. Still thoroughly confused.

Comment: Migrating VB6 to VB.Net can be [quite hard](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vb6-migration), especially if you're not much of a VB person! I recommend some [background reading](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/dd408373.aspx#migrate).

Answer (score 1):

Is...

```
Private ASPResponse As ASPTypeLibrary.Response
Set ASPResponse = objContext("Response")
```

...*Post* VB.NET conversion?  If so, you'll need to explicitly cast `objContext("Response")` into the `ASPTypeLibrary.Response` object.  This especially applies if `Option Strict` is on. e.g.

```
ASPResponse = CType(objContext("Response"), ASPTypeLibary.Response)
```

Also, *Set* and *Let* statements aren't supported in VB.NET.

Comment: you're right, George.  I just looked closer at the Activate method, and edited the above.  The actual line that sets ASPResponse is now shown there. (ASPResponse = ContextUtil.GetNamedProperty("Response"))

Comment: `Option Strict` is probably off, since the code has been migrated from VB6

Comment: @MarkJ  That's a possibility -- never hurts to look though ;)

Answer (score 0):

This MAY have to do with the way the COM component's host is activated.  I read another post ([Klaus H. Probst])[1](http://www.ureader.com/msg/1639158.aspx) that indicated that, in order to access the Response element, the COM component had to be activated as a Library (as opposed to Server) so that it was running in the ASP process space.  So I tried changing the Activation type of the Component's hosting application to library, resetting and rebuilding a few times, and now I'm able to access the Cookies element of the Response.  However, my co-worker is still running the host application as a Server, and has no problem.